# Modules and submodules

Tags: representation-theory, modules

Let $G=S_n = Sym_n$ be the symmetric group and $V$ a vector space with basis $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$, then $V$ is a module with action defined by $g$. $v_i$=$v_{g(i)}$ for 1$\leq$i $\leq$ n and extending linearly.

First, show $U=\langle v_1-v_2,v_2-v_3,...,v_{n-1}-v_n\rangle$ is a sub-module of $V$.

I can see the general idea for this is to show it is first a subspace (so not empty and closed under vector addition) and then show it remains closed under the action defined for V.

The next part is where it becomes odd; as I am lead to understand under most fields, namely $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, $U$ is irreducible. However, under F=$\mathbb{F}_p$, for $p \mid n$.

I know I can show it is reducible in this case by finding a submodule, $W$ of $U$ such that $W \neq U$ and W not being the zero-module. However I cannot think of a way to find such a module.

Comment: Looks like $G$ is assumed to be a subgroup of $Sym(n)$?

Comment: We are told that $G=Sym(n)$

Comment: $g:v_i\mapsto v_{g(i)}$ is a right action, not a left action. Just something to be careful about in case it's ever relevant. Also, what leads you to believe $U$ is irreducible with $\Bbb C$?

Comment: @user115802 $U$ can be reducible. By the way, what were you going to say at the end of your second to last paragraph? The last sentence is a fragment.

Comment: @rschwieb: I think he he is saying that over $\mathbb{}$ the representation/module is irreducible (which it is), but over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ it isn't if $p\mid n$.

Comment: Yes that is correct. We have been told that U is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, however under the case of a finite field it isn't - the problem boils down to finding a proper submodule of $U$ when F=$\mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: @user115802: Do you understand how when $p=2$ and $n$ is even, then $\langle v_1 + \dots v_n\rangle$ is an invariant subspace?

Comment: Care to explain how that works? We have never really been shown how to look for subspaces

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so for $p\mid n$ first do as @rschwieb suggests and prove that you can write
$$
U = \langle v_1 - v_2 , \dots , v_1 - v_n\rangle.
$$
That is, you have to convince yourself that $\{v_1 - v_2 , \dots , v_1 - v_n\}$ is a basis. That is, you want to show that this set spans all of $U$ and that the set is linearly independent. The linear independence should be clear, and as a hint for how to show that the set spans all of $U$ note, for example that $v_2 - v_3 = (v_2 - v_3) - (v_1 - v_2)$.

Then note that 
$$\begin{align*}
(v_1 -v_2) + (v_1 - v_3) + \dots +(v_1 - v_n) &= (n-1)v_1 - (v_2 +v_3 + \dots + v_n ) \\ 
&= -(v_1 + \dots + v_n) \in U.
\end{align*}
$$
And so
$$
W = \langle v_1 + \dots + v_n\rangle
$$
is a one dimensional invariant subspace of $W$